# Elastic match for dictionary with dictionary using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good morning, I am trying to learn how to query elastic and I have an scenario that I am not able to find the solution, I have a `Dictionary<Guid, List<int>>` stored on Elastic as:

```
"myStoredDictionary": {
    "guidA": [14],
    "guidB": [16,17],
    "guidC": [30,31]}
```

And I want with a other dictionaries with the same structure to match results so:

this ones should match:

```
"mySearchDictionary1": {
    "guidA": [14,15],
    "guidB": [16],
    "guidC": [30]}

"mySearchDictionary2": {
    "guidA": [14],
    "guidB": [16]}

"mySearchDictionary3": {
    "guidA": [14,15],
    "guidX": [0]
}
```

So basically the logic is: for each key that exists on both dictionaries the stored dictionary should have at least 1 of the ints from the search list.

Can someone give me some tips on how I should approach this? Thanks!

Comment: so you got a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by storing all the ints as a simple array, ignoring the guid:

```
"values": [4,14,17,30]
```

And then using must with a terms per guid do the trick:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "terms": { "values": [4,41,42,43] } },
                { "terms": { "values": [14,141,142,143] } },
                { "terms": { "values": [17,171,172,173] } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So if at least one of the entries on the terms array is on the values list, is a match.